# Windows Server AD 2022 - Add a domain user to the local group "Remote Desktop Users" via GPO using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, group-policy, gpo

I must add a domain user to the local group "Remote Desktop Users" via GPO.

And since I'm building Domain Controller images in an automated way, I want to create a policy to set a domain user as part of the Remote Desktop Users local group of each domain joined Windows client machine using PowerShell.

I've been trying to manage the Restricted Groups from a GPO via PowerShell, but without success.
I found the following code, but it returns only a .xml that I can check the groups located at the Restricted Groups from a GPO.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a956c361-3852-4ec2-a6e3-15475e67bdaa/listing-gpo-restricted-groups-with-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell

If there's a way to export the GPO as .XML or any other format and edit it and import that changes, it would be also fine.

Another forum that I found and it's a good solution but it's still manually, is the following one. I'd like to automate that steps via PowerShell, but it has been hard to do.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/using-group-policy-preferences-to-manage-the-local-administrator/ba-p/259223

Please, does anyone know some automated way to create a GPO that includes a domain user to a local group?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try **Invoke-Command** and **Add-LocalGroupMember**

ForEach ($ServerName in $Servers)
{    
   Invoke-command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop User" -Member "Admin02", "MicrosoftAccount\username@Outlook.com", "AzureAD\DavidChew@contoso.com", "CONTOSO\Admins"}
}
```

Comment: That's a good one, but I was wondering how can I make it reusable because it looks like an one shot script. Right? I need something that's be applied via GPO and if there's a new domain joined client, the domain user must be included to its "Remote Desktop User" local group. And if the user is modified or it was decided to remove it from the group, it must be managed by the GPO.

Comment: so probably powershell isn't necessary. You can try create GPO Computer Configuration / Policies / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Restricted Groups  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20402.active-directory-group-policy-restricted-groups.aspx

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20402.active-directory-group-policy-restricted-groups.aspx

Create new GPO: Computer Configuration / Policies / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Restricted Groups

or if neecessary is done by powershell script create GPO
[Configuring PowerShell Startup Scripts with Group Policy](http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/)

and launch script:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop User" -Member "Admin02", "MicrosoftAccount\username@Outlook.com", "AzureAD\DavidChew@contoso.com", "CONTOSO\Admins"
```